# Replacing char with hex based on text table

Tags: c#, hex

This post might be more theory than code.

I was wondering if there is a (relatively) `simple` way to use a text table (basically an array of chars) and replace the chars in a string based on their value.

Let me elaborate.

Let's say we have this two line table:

```
table[0x0] = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'};
table[0x1] = new char[] {'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ']', ',', '/', '.', '~', '&'};
```

Each array has 16 members, 0-F in hex.

Say we have a string "hello" converted to hex (68 65 6C 6C 6F). I want to take these hex numbers, and map them to the new locations as defined in the table above.

So, "hello" would now look like this:

```
07 04 0B 0B 0E
```

I can easily convert the string into an array, but I am stuck on what to do next. I feel a foreach loop would do the trick, but it's exact contents I do not yet know.

Is there an easy way to do this? It seems like it shouldn't be too hard, but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing it.

Thank you very much for any help at all!

Comment: I think you're looking for the `IndexOf` method.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes I am.

Comment: What role do your two arrays play here? Don't really understand how you map 68 to 08 using this so called 'table'. What you have done for your sample 'hello' is just subtract 60(hex) from each char.

Comment: @SergeyS I messed up, the new "hello" would be "07 04 0B 0B 0E". The point of this, is that I'm making a hex editor for a Playstation 1 video game so I can translate it. I need the table because the characters in the game don't map to normal hex. They use their own table, which I decoded. This is only a part of the full table.

Comment: So what does `q` map to?

Comment: In this example, `q` maps to 0x10. In the full table, it maps to 0x40, but that's irrelevant here.

Comment: 0x10, because there are 0x10 in the first array. So why does it need to be in a separate char array? Having a two-dimensional array greatly complicates this, and I think it's unnecessary.  Just concatenate them all together as one long lookup table.

Comment: I guess you're right. But, if I did that, I would still have the problem of not knowing how to replace the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static readonly char[] TABLE = {
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
    'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ']', ',', '/', '.', '~', '&',
};

// Make a lookup dictionary of char => index in the table, for speed.
static readonly Dictionary<char, int> s_lookup = TABLE.ToDictionary(
            c => c,                          // Key is the char itself.
            c => Array.IndexOf(TABLE, c));   // Value is the index of that char.

static void Main(string[] args) {

    // The test input string. Note it has no space.
    string str = "hello,world.";

    // For each character in the string, we lookup what its index in the
    // original table was.
    IEnumerable<int> indices = str.Select(c => s_lookup[c]);

    // Print those numbers out, first converting them to two-digit hex values,
    // and then joining them with commas in-between.
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", indices.Select(i => i.ToString("X02"))));
}
```

Output:

```
07,04,0B,0B,0E,1B,16,0E,11,0B,03,1D
```

Note that if you provide an input character that isn't in the lookup table, you're not going to notice it right away!  `Select` returns an `IEnumerable`, that is lazily-evaluated only when you go to use it. At that point, if the input character is not found, the dictionary `[]` call will throw an exeception.

One way to make this more obvious is to call `ToArray()` after the Select, so you have an array of indices, and not an `IEnumerable`. This will force the evaluation to happen immediately:

```
int[] indices = str.Select(c => s_lookup[c]).ToArray();
```

Reference:

- [`Array.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.indexof.aspx)
- [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx)
- [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)
- [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876.aspx)

Comment: You sir, are amazing! I don't know much about Dictionaries, so I would've never gotten that. Thank you so much!

Comment: This uses a lot of stuff from `System.Linq`, but hopefully it makes sense to you, and isn't a few lines of voodoo that end up in your code, confusing as all hell.  I suggest you checkout the MSDN documentation and *understand* what each line does.

Comment: I don't know much about Linq yet, but I'll make sure to do my best to understand it all.